# Как заменить элемент?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(function () {
    console.log('test start');
   $('.mytest').click(function () {
     var html = '<button>test</button>';
   $(this).after(html);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="mytest">test1</button>
<button class="mytest">test2</button>
<button class="mytest">test3</button>
```

Нужно чтобы при повторном клике `'<button>test</button>'` заменялся на такой же элемент `'<button>test</button>'`, а не добавлялся новый `'<button>test</button>'`.

Comment: заменялся на что?

Comment: что значит заменялся ? заменялся бы новым элементом или содержимое спана заменялось бы?

Comment: Нажмите выполнить скрипт увидите что при нажатии на кнопку добавляется слово test  это слово должно добавляться при клике заменяя предыдущее если оно уже было добавлено

Comment: [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

Answer (score 1):

Можно удалять предыдущий `<span>` перед добавлением нового:

```js
$(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $('.mytest').click(function() {
        $(this).next('span').remove();
        var html = '<span>test' + i + '</span>';
        $(this).after(html);
        i++;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="mytest">test1</button>
<button class="mytest">test2</button>
<button class="mytest">test3</button>
```

А вообще, для смены текста внутри `<span>` лучше не пересоздавать каждый раз `<span>`, а просто менять текст в единожды созданном:

```js
$(function () {
    var i = 0;
    var $buttons = $('.mytest');
    var html = '<span></span>';
    $buttons.after(html);
    $buttons.on("click", function() {
        var text = 'test' + i;
        $(this).next().text(text);
        i++;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="mytest">test1</button>
<button class="mytest">test2</button>
<button class="mytest">test3</button>
```

Comment: А что если вместо span будет button? разве нет какого то более изящного решения =)

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich вы добавляете не только `<span>`-ы, или вы про ситуацию, когда `<span>` ещё ни разу не добавлялся?

Comment: да когда мы вместо span будем добавлять button при первом клике удалится button следующий за нажатым элементом

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich более изящное решение есть: перестать добавлять `<span>` каждый раз, создав их при загрузке страницы. А затем лишь менять в них текст. Но я ведь не знаю, почему вы именно создаёте `<span>` - может, вам надо именно создавать при каждом клике.

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich нет, не удалится. Можете в этом убедиться, нажав на "Выполнить код" в моём ответе.

Comment: Нажимаем на 1-й button удаляется 2-й

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich нет, не удаляется. `'span'` внутри `.next('span')` написано не просто так. А вот ваше изменение текста вопроса пару минут назад, кардинально меняющее решение, - это вообще "подсудное дело". Так дела не делаются.

Comment: Я для того изменил чтобы было понятней что я имею ввиду когда говорю что удалиться button

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich ещё раз: в варианте с добавлением `<span>` после `<button>` никакие `<button>` не удалятся благодаря `'span'` внутри `.next()`. Рабочий пример есть в ответе. Если же вы добавляете не только `<span>`, но и любой другой тег (а об этом нужно было сразу упоминать в вопросе), то это совсем другая история.